# Is there a alternative to installing android emulator during flutter dev for low end pc?

Tags: android, performance, flutter, android-emulator, slowdown

I am getting started with flutter. After a day of installing all the required stuff and running an android emulator for the first time, I figured that my pc is not powerful enough for running android without significantly slowing down the computer.
(Nope, I cant upgrade my pc.)

I was wondering if there is any way I can do flutter on my pc. Any way to get something like ui output on dartpad.

I am using VSCode.

Comment: you can work with flutter web . ALso  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @griffins mentioned, you can use flutter web. Also, another option is to use a physical Android device, assuming you have one that you can connect to your computer for development.
If you simply want to prototype designs, codepen.io recently added Flutter support.

Comment: I've come from game dev.  The game engines work pretty well on my pc. I also tried ai and even that works okay. 
It's kinda silly that UI dev doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an android phone, just [turn on developer mode and USB debugging](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/AndroidUSBDebugging_Windows10.htm) on it and connect it to your computer and click run. Then the apk file will be installed on your phone and it will instantly change states whenever you click run. If you don't have an android phone you can easily get a decent one for just under $50.

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical android device, you can connect it to your computer. and type `flutter run` in your terminal.

or

use flutter web(beta) type `flutter run -d chrome` in your terminal.